# How to get distribution code name by using Itamae and ohai

Tags: ruby, ubuntu, itamae

I want to get distribution code name by using Itamae.

#### recipe.rb

```
require 'pp'
pp node[:platform] #=> ubuntu
pp node[:platform_version] #=> 14.04
pp node[:lsb] #=> nil
pp node[:codename] #=> nil
```

As you see I could get os name and version of it, but couldn't get code name like `trusty`.

If I login the server and run a command `lsb_release -cs`, then it return `trusty`.

How can I get the code name from `Itamae`?

Comment: Where does `node` come from? [Itamae](https://github.com/itamae-kitchen/itamae)?

Comment: Probably automatically defined by `Itamae`. I'm just running a command `itamae ssh -h myserver -u ironsand recipe.rb`.

Comment: I'd have a look at what's in `node.inspect` before making expectations as to what it should do.

Comment: `node.inspect` contains quite a lot of information that I can't find out which are sensitive and which is not. So I can't put it here. Anyways there is not a word `trusty` in the text.

Comment: You may need to dig into the docs of Itamae some more.

Comment: Thanks, then I'd rather hard coding the "trusty".

Comment: The reason why there is no platform family there is because Specinfra does not provide it, as per: [platform.rb](https://github.com/chef/ohai/blob/master/lib/ohai/plugins/linux/platform.rb). And Itamae relies on Specinfra a lot. There is an option to utilise Ohai from Chef, Inc., but I would not recommend it a very heady-weight alternative since it relies on Chef being installed, see [this](https://github.com/itamae-kitchen/itamae/blob/master/lib/itamae/runner.rb).